# Jquery reinitialize .each function when adding dynamic content

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I am using FullCalendar and Scheduler - when removing events from the calendar I am adding them back into the External Events div - but I need to reinitialize the .each function below

```
$('#external-events .fc-event').each(function() {

    // store data so the calendar knows to render an event upon drop
    $(this).data('event', {
        title: $.trim($(this).text()), // use the element's text as the event title
        stick: true, // maintain when user navigates (see docs on the renderEvent method)
        id: $(this).attr('id'),
        overlap: false
    });

    // make the event draggable using jQuery UI
    $(this).draggable({
        zIndex: 999,
        revert: true,      // will cause the event to go back to its
        revertDuration: 0  //  original position after the drag
    });

});
```

Obviously I can just throw the same function in one of the button functions on the .dialog that I throw to confirm the removal of the event, but I don't want to duplicate code.

I was trying something like this with no luck.

```
function externalEvents() {
    // store data so the calendar knows to render an event upon drop
    $(this).data('event', {
        title: $.trim($(this).text()), // use the element's text as the event title
        stick: true, // maintain when user navigates (see docs on the renderEvent method)
        id: $(this).attr('id'),
        overlap: false
    });

    // make the event draggable using jQuery UI
    $(this).draggable({
        zIndex: 999,
        revert: true,      // will cause the event to go back to its
        revertDuration: 0  //  original position after the drag
    });
}

$('#external-events .fc-event').each(externalEvents());
```

My thought process being I can just run

```
$('#external-events .fc-event').each(externalEvents());
```

Whenever add more elements to the external-events div.

This throws an error `TypeError: invalid 'in' operand a`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `externalEvents` when you have parentheses after it. You want to pass it to `each` as a function reference.

```
$('#external-events .fc-event').each(externalEvents);
```